# Issue tracking system for an hospital?

Tags: tracking, jira

I've a friend working in an hospital and he asked for an issue tracking system. 
Currently they are using only mails. I thought to Jira or Trac, but they use
"programming terms" like "bug" or "patch". 
I don't want to spend time customizing, do you know any better solution/software?

Comment: Use right tool for job: http://www.logisoft.hr/en/solutions/issue-tracking-system specifically designed for hospitals. Send contact message for details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used Trac to implement issue tracking for managing the operations of a building. It is quite configurable, so I was able to conceal the software-bug-oriented wording without a lot of effort, though the admin interface.

I applied a trivial patch to Trac so that it displays boolean values as Y and N rather than the the "computerese" 1 and 0, and also, so that the false value is displayed a blank. (This is better in a columnar report where you have boolean columns, and you just want to clearly see where the Y values are; they are harder to see in a grid of Y's and N's).

Here it is below. Everything else, I did easily through the admin interface.

```
Index: pyshared/trac/ticket/web_ui.py
===================================================================
--- pyshared.orig/trac/ticket/web_ui.py     2011-09-16 11:59:40.000000000 -0700
+++ pyshared/trac/ticket/web_ui.py  2011-09-16 12:11:31.000000000 -0700
@@ -1120,7 +1120,7 @@
             elif type_ == 'checkbox':
                 value = ticket.values.get(name)
                 if value in ('1', '0'):
-                    field['rendered'] = value == '1' and _('yes') or _('no')
+                    field['rendered'] = value == '1' and 'yes' or ''

             # ensure sane defaults
             field.setdefault('optional', False)
Index: pyshared/trac/ticket/query.py
===================================================================
--- pyshared.orig/trac/ticket/query.py      2011-09-16 14:36:51.000000000 -0700
+++ pyshared/trac/ticket/query.py   2011-09-16 14:37:10.000000000 -0700
@@ -294,9 +294,9 @@
                     val = datetime.fromtimestamp(int(val or 0), utc)
                 elif field and field['type'] == 'checkbox':
                     try:
-                        val = bool(int(val))
+                        val = val == '1' and 'Y' or ''
                     except TypeError, ValueError:
-                        val = False
+                        val = ''
                 result[name] = val
             results.append(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

I know you said that you didn't want to time customizing, but I am afraid you are just out of luck on that. I doubt that there is any issue tracking system out there that will give you exactly what you want without customizing (or without exorbitant fees). So I will still recommend JIRA.

JIRA is incredibly customizable. We use it in our organization for tracking issues of many types from software issue tracking, to Vehicle reservations, to building maintenance work order requests, purchase request, and more. We also have plans to customize it for our students (I work in a college) to be able to request assistance with registration, submit feedback, and more.

JIRA is incredibly robust and, once you get the hang of it, not terrible to configure.  I won't lie. Configuring JIRA, at first, is a chore and can be difficult to get a handle on. But there is a great book from O'Reilly called Jira Administration that helped me understand it all much better. And it is quite a small book (187 pages or so), so it is not filled with a bunch of fluff. It is just great and useful information.

We use JIRA Dashboards, Issue type customizations, notification schemes, permission schemes, issue type security, custom workflows, custom screens and forms, plugins, the Web Service APIs, and more. It really is a fantastic system.